# How to access enironment variables of a popen process

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Consider I have two python scripts `caller.py` and `being_called.py`

**Caller.py:**

```
p = Popen(path_to_being_called, shell=True, stdout=fh, stderr=fh1)
```

path_to_being_called contains executable path of script 'being_called.py'

Now **being_called.py** does following:

```
os.environ['hello'] = 'Yolo'
```

*I want to access this value of environment variable hello inside the script caller.py*

Is there a way to do this with popen calls? 
Note that I know I can update environment variable for 'being_called' from caller itself as a paramter `env` and mapping of os.environ and kwargs, but thats not what I want to do. Env variable will be updated from being_called.py only and I need to access its value in caller.py

I tried to see what `dir(p)` offers but not getting any help from any of that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There are much, much better and more elegant ways to exchange information between scripts

Comment: General stuff like imports or function calls wont work for me since It is a very complicated long, old written framework (test harness) I am working on, which has this same flow for executing many test scripts through popen

Comment: Can't give a satisfactory answer to your question unless I were to explain complete framework but believe me, this is my only choice

Comment: Have you considered not using popen, and instead directly calling the methods?

Comment: @Natecat, That is not really my choice to make and doing something like that would require changes to be done to thousand other things in harness.

Comment: Can you edit `being_called.py`? If you can make even small edits, this might become doable.

Comment: @Bi Rico yes I can definitely do that. Being_called is a testcase being run by framework and is independent. Pls suggest

Comment: @MohitC, if you can then why not just print it and capture it? There are lots of easy ways to do it if you can modify the script

Comment: Yes printing it and scanning it with a regex in stdout would be my last choice ultimately. But it was like several test scripts already got it in their environment variables so was looking forward to access it from those only to avoid changes all over. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't see any easy way to do it without modifying, the only command I know to get the updated env would be `cat /proc/self/environ` in the process itself, as far as I understand what is suggested in the answer below would not work as `/proc/pid/environ` is not updated.

Comment: You could shadow `os.environ`, have it print to stdout or send the info via a socket or queue on `__setitem__`. Then pass along calls to the original `os.environ`.

Comment: @BiRico, can show an example code? I don't get how exactly it would be passed to original os.environ